# Using async socket in Tasks

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

I have an application that is processing items in a FIFO queue using Tasks in .net 4.0.

I am new to TPL and Tasks in .net and was wondering if there is an easy solution to my problem:

The Action delegate in the Task is assigned to a method that is sending and receiving data on an asynchronous socket. The problem I am having is that the Task ends "prematurely". How do I tell the Task to wait until all communication is completed before processing the next item in the queue?

One solution is to switch to using a synchronous socket, but I was hoping there is a way to do this using the async socket.

**EDIT**
Added some code:

```
class Program
{
    private BlockingCollection<string> myQueue;
    private CancellationTokenSource cancellationSignalForConsumeTask;
    private CancellationTokenSource cancellationSignalForProcessCommandTask;
    private AsyncSocket mySocket;

    public void Main(string[] args)
   {
       mySocket = new mySocket();
       myscoket.ReceiveData += mySocket_ReceiveData;

       cancellationSignalForConsumeTask = new CancellationTokenSource();
       Task listenerTask = Task.Factory.StartNew((obj) => Consume(),
                                                          cancellationSignalForConsumeTask.Token,
                                                          TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

        while (true)
        {}
   }

    private void Consume()
    {
       while (!myQueue.IsCompleted )
            {
                string _item = myQueue.Take();

                cancellationSignalForProcessCommandTask = new CancellationTokenSource();
                Task t = new Task(() => 
                    {
                        cancellationSignalForProcessCommandTask.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                        DoSomeWork(_item);
                    }, cancellationSignalForProcessCommandTask.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

                t.Start();
                t.Wait();
            }
    }

    private void DoSomeWork(string _item)
    {
       mySocket.SendData("Data to server that could take a long time to process")
    }

    private void mySocket_ReceiveData(string dataFromServer)
    {
        string returnMessage = dataFromServer;

        //I want the Task to end here...

    }
}
```

The problem is that the Task ends when the `DoSomeWork()` method finishes (and I understand why), is there a way I can manually tell the Task to end through the `CancellationTokenSource` object maybe?

Comment: Probably a Wait() on the root thread/task. Can you show what code you have so far?

Comment: Post what you have so far.

Comment: What's `AsyncSocket`? If `SendData()` is asynchronous, then you probably need to `await` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to wait on the task the *receives* the data, but you're currently waiting on the task that *sends* the data. One way to do so would be to use a construct like [`AutoResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private AutoResetEvent autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

private void Consume()
{
   while (!myQueue.IsCompleted )
        {
            string _item = myQueue.Take();

            cancellationSignalForProcessCommandTask = new CancellationTokenSource();
            Task t = new Task(() => 
                {
                    cancellationSignalForProcessCommandTask.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    DoSomeWork(_item);
                }, cancellationSignalForProcessCommandTask.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

            t.Start();

            // Wait for data to be received.
            // This line will block until autoResetEvent.Set() is called.
            autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
        }
}

private void mySocket_ReceiveData(string dataFromServer)
{
    string returnMessage = dataFromServer;

   // Notify other threads that data was received and that processing can continue.
   autoResetEvent.Set();
}
```

This is only an example of using `AutoResetEvent` - you'd probably want to refine it to suit your needs.

Comment: Note that you should be careful when synchronizing threads. For example, if `DoSomeWork` sends two separate strings of data, you'd want to call `Set` only after all data has been received - otherwise, the second task will start before the first was finished.